# What it means if someone says,"it's getting to that point in the evening".

Tags: american-english, translation

Hello ladies and gentlemen, it is my first time that i try to translate a film to my own language , and i have got now a problem because i do not know what it means. So, please everyone help me. Okey?

Comment: Time for bed, time for a drink, time to stop working...It really depends on the context.

Comment: @AffableAmbler omg you blast it for me , you know? I really thank you. A lot of kisses 

Comment: Which one was it?

Comment: @AffableAmbler  it meant,"hey it's time to stop this work". Because i am trying to translate this movie "the grey".

Comment: @AffableAmbler  And sorry to ask you something more , what it means "fucking to each his own" ??

Comment: @BwarO.Rasul , sounds like another question to be posted.

Comment: Is there no punctuation between `fucking` and `to each his own`? To each his own, basically just means the equivalent of `live and let live`; e.g., let people proceed with their own actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure of speech... means an interruption to the flow of the conversation.

Comment: No offense but this is not exactly correct. It's a polite way to say, "the party's over", "let's all get ready to go home", "it's about time for bed", etc... A polite way to break up the activity and end it.

Answer (score 1):

That is a common idiom which is used as a way to politely end the activity of the evening. It's another way of saying other colloquial references (i.e.): **"party's over folks", "it's getting late, time for bed", "why don't we all gather our things and wrap up", and so on.**

It can be used for a party or small "get together" or for a work event; really any kind of social gathering is where you might hear this figure of speech.

Again, the easiest way to explain it's meaning: **"it's getting late and we should wrap up (end activities) and go home"**.